# RxSwift: code working only first time

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm new in RxSwift. Some strange thing happens in my code.
I have a collection view and

> Driver["String"]

Data for binding.

```
var items = fetchImages("flower")   
 items.asObservable().bindTo(self.collView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("cell", cellType: ImageViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
           cell.imageView.setURL(NSURL(string: element), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))           
}.addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

> fetchImages

Function returns data

```
private func fetchImages(string:String) -> Driver<[String]> {

        let searchData = Observable.just(string)
        return searchData.observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(globalConcurrentQueueQOS: .Background))
            .flatMap
            { text in // .Background thread, network request

                return RxAlamofire
                    .requestJSON(.GET, "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=2557096-723b632d4f027a1a50018f846&q=\(text)&image_type=photo")
                    .debug()
                    .catchError { error in
                        print("aaaa")
                        return Observable.never()
                }
            }
            .map { (response, json) -> [String] in // again back to .Background, map objects
                var arr = [String]()
                for  i in 0 ..< json["hits"]!!.count {
                     arr.append(json["hits"]!![i]["previewURL"]!! as! String)
                }

                return arr
            }
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance) // switch to MainScheduler, UI updates
            .doOnError({ (type) in
                print(type)
            })
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: []) // This also makes sure that we are on MainScheduler
    }
```

Strange thing is this. First time when I fetch with "flower" it works and return data, but when I add this code

```
self.searchBar.rx_text.subscribeNext { text in
      items = self.fetchImages(text)
}.addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

It doesn't work. It doesn't steps in flatmap callback, and because of this, doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in your first use case, because you're actually using the returned `Driver<[String]>` via a `bindTo()`:

```
var items = fetchImages("flower")
items.asObservable().bindTo(...
```

However, in your second use case, you aren't doing anything with the returned `Driver<[String]>` other than saving it to a variable, which you do nothing with.

```
items = self.fetchImages(text)
```

A `Driver` does nothing until you `subscribe` to it (or in your case `bindTo`).

EDIT: To make this clearer, here's how you could get your second use case to work (I've avoided cleaning up the implementation to keep it simple):

```
self.searchBar.rx_text
.flatMap { searchText in
    return self.fetchImages(searchText)
}
.bindTo(self.collView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("cell", cellType: ImageViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
    cell.imageView.setURL(NSURL(string: element), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))           
}.addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

Comment: Yea,i agree with it,but the problem is,second time self.fetchImages(text) doesnt return anything,the RxAlamofire .requestJSON doesnt call.It seams that flatmap callback doesnt steps in and because of that the call doesnt called

Comment: What do you mean by "second time"?  You've shown two different uses of your `fetchImages`.  Do you mean you're using both, and the second way doesn't work if it comes later?  Or do you mean that you're only using the last use case and it does work, but only once?

Comment: I use both,first i call function with "flowers" and its return data,second time i use text from search bar and it doesnt return anything.

Comment: Yea, so my point still stands.  When you `subscribeNext` on the `rx_text` `Observable`, you're just calling `fetchImages` and getting a *new* `Driver`, but you aren't doing anything with it.  Unless you `subscribe` or `bindTo` it, it does *nothing*.  You might be thinking that `Observable.just(...)` will cause it to immediately start, but it doesn't.  It's waiting for you to `subscribe` or `bindTo` it.  It has all the potential to `just` and `flatMap`, but it won't until you `subscribe` or `bindTo` it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you a way to get it to work with minimal changes.  There are still improvements that could be made, but they aren't essential to the question and would make the answer less clear.

Comment: Thanks,this is what I want